# Import curl into postman

Tags: curl, postman

I'm working with an api endpoint that has the following curl. When I import the curl into postman, the key column is populated with both the key and the value.

[image]

```
curl "https://{{Environments}}/v1/initiate" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"
-X POST \
-d '{
      "clientId": "1234",
      "password": "5678",
      "pairingCode": "9101112"
     }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` header to the request:

```
curl "https://{{Environments}}/v1/initiate" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{
      "clientId": "1234",
      "password": "5678",
      "pairingCode": "9101112"
    }'
```

When I copy the code above into Postman:

[image: Postman]